# Android ObjectAnimator vs ViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: java, android, objectanimator, animator, viewpropertyanimator

What's the difference between ObjectAnimator and ViewPropertyAnimator changing property value?

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myObject, "X", 0.0f, 100.0f);
```

I tried `myObject.getX()` while above `objectAnimator` is ongoing, and I got a on-the-way value between 0.0f to 100.0.

```
myObject.setX(0.0f);
myObject.animate().x(100.0f);
```

However, I got precise 100.0 when I `myObject.getX()`'d while above `ViewPropertyAnimator` is ongoing.

I can't figure out what makes this difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you request to animate the `x` field using a `ViewPropertyAnimator`, it doesn't actually animate the `x` field - it animates the `translateX` field. This is why you can't see the `x` field change.

From the Android source code in **ViewPropertyAnimator.java**:

```
case X:
    renderNode.setTranslationX(value - mView.mLeft);
    break;
```

`ObjectAnimator` on the other hand uses reflection to animate properties - rather than a preset list of supported actions. And so when you tell it to animate the "`X`" field, it calls "`setX`" directly.

Comment: What about ViewPropertyAnimator.translationX()?
Does that mean ViewPropertyAnimator.x() and translationX() are actually the same?

Comment: translationX also affects the translationX, just without compensating with the view's mLeft value.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Do you have any reference?

Comment: Yes, the android source code (see method setValue(int, float)): https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.java

Comment: How about using ViewPropertyAnimator.x() ? This will play with the actual position of the view.

Comment: Please check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044088/android-object-animator-frame-issue
@GilMoshayof

Comment: i don't think this is true anymore (Android 28 code does not do this)